# Basics of classes and objects: Java

Tags: java, class, object, public

The question that I received:

Define a class hotel with the following specifications:

Private members:

```
Roomno            
Name
Charges_day     
No_of_days
```

Public members:

```
Getit()      -to enter the data members
Showit()  to show the data member
Compute()   -To calculate and return the total charges as charges_day * No_of_days
```

and a constructor function to initialize the data members.

---

The code I wrote:

```
public class hotel{
    private int Roomno;
    private String Name; 
    private int Charges_day; 
    private int No_of_days;

    public hotel(){
        Roomno = 0; 
        Name = "";
        Charges_day = 0;
        No_of_days = 0; 
    }

    public void Getit(int r, String n, int c, int no){
        Roomno = r; 
        Name = n;
        Charges_day = c;
        No_of_days = no;
    }

    public String Showname(){
        return Name;
    }
    public int  Showit(){
        return Roomno;
        return Charges_day;
        return No_of_days;
    }

    public int Compute(){
        return (Charges_day*No_of_days); 
    }

}
```

I am aware that I can't have more than 1 returns in one method function, but I'm unable to find a way around this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @OldProgrammer have I asked something in a way it shouldn't be asked?

Comment: @DhruvGarg It's okay now, but your formatting was bad so the last sentence was hard to see.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the requirement, I'd suggest you just print the values

```
public void Showit(){
    System.out.println(Name+" "+Roomno+" "+Charges_day+" "+No_of_days);
}
```

If you need a method that return a `String` representation of your object, override `toString()`

```
public String toString(){
    return Name + " " + Roomno + " " + Charges_day + " " + No_of_days;
}
```

---

Also Java convention for naming is

- lowerCamelCase for methods and attributs

Comment: Thank you so much.